# Find sequences of NA values in data.frame rows

Tags: r, dataframe, rcpp, sequences, na

I have a huge `data.frame` with several `NA` values in it. It seems that I get problems, if many `NA` values occur sequently.

Is there an easy way to find those rows in which `NA` values occur e.g. 20 times one after another, but not the ones where 20 `NA` values occur isolated?

**EDIT** (added by agstudy)

The accepted solution uses `apply` which is not very efficient for hudge matrix. So I edit the solution (I add the `Rcpp` tag) to ask for more **efficient solution**.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  You could remove the >20NA rows per agstudy's answers, or it might be more expedient to put a `try-catch` into your existing code so that a "bad" row doesn't crash your function.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the edit is mine. Sorry.

Comment: @agstudy Your edit is fine -- I just wondered whether the root difficulty of the original question could be handled in a different manner.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I just needed an overview to see if, where and how many of those NA sequences hide in the data and find out if this might be the reason for the error I get. I use a function I did not write myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function anlagous to `complete.cases` that computes consecutive missings values using `rle`:

```
cons.missings <- 
function(dat,n)
apply(is.na(dat),1,function(x){
  yy <- rle(x)
  any(yy$lengths[yy$values]>n)
})
```

Then to keep only good rows:

```
dat[!cons.missings(dat,20),]
```

Example with 4 connectives missings values:

```
dat <- as.matrix(t(data.frame(a= c(1,rep(NA,4),5),
           b= c(2,rep(NA,2),1,rep(NA,2)))))

 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
a    1   NA   NA   NA   NA    5
b    2   NA   NA    1   NA   NA

dat[!cons.missings(dat,3),]
[1]  2 NA NA  1 NA NA
```

Comment: The solution works ok for me. I need it mainly to get an overview over the NA sequences in the dataset. If simply remove or not I have to decide later. Thank you!

Comment: @aldorado is it efficient as you want?

Comment: efficient enough and quite demoralizing. If really the NA sequences is the reason for the errors, I have to remove a lot of data before using it.

Answer (score 2):

Although not "Rcpp" as you asked, here is an alternative using `.Call`, that seems valid:

```
library(inline)

ff = cfunction(sig = c(R_mat = "matrix", R_n = "numeric"), body = '
    SEXP mat, dims, ans;

    PROTECT(mat = coerceVector(R_mat, REALSXP)); //or `as.numeric(.)` in R
    PROTECT(dims = getAttrib(R_mat, R_DimSymbol));
    R_len_t rows = INTEGER(dims)[0], cols = INTEGER(dims)[1];
    R_len_t n = INTEGER(coerceVector(R_n, INTSXP))[0];

    R_len_t *buf = (int *) R_alloc(rows, sizeof(int)), b = 0; //dynamic allocation 
                                                             //of a pointer to store 
                                                             //the indices of rows
                                                          //that match the criterion.
                                                           //a classic usage of this
                                                         //is in do_which (summary.c)

    double *pmat = REAL(mat);  //pointer to the matrix input
    for(int ir = 0; ir < rows; ir++) {
       R_len_t COUNT_CONS_NAS = 0;
       for(int ic = 0; ic < cols; ic++) {
           if(ISNAN(pmat[ir + ic*rows])) { //if NA is found
               COUNT_CONS_NAS++;          //start counting NAs  
               if(COUNT_CONS_NAS == n) break;  //no need to search all columns
           }
           else {
               COUNT_CONS_NAS = 0; //if not NA, counter back to zero 
           }
       }
       if(COUNT_CONS_NAS == n) {  //if the specific row matched the criterion
           buf[b] = ir + 1;   //store its index
           b++;
       }
    }

    PROTECT(ans = allocVector(INTSXP, b));  //allocate a vector with 
                                           //length = No rows that matched criterion
    memcpy(INTEGER(ans), buf, sizeof(int)*b);  //copy rows indices to 
                                               //the pointer of ans

    UNPROTECT(3);

    return(ans);
')


set.seed(11);mat = matrix(sample(c(NA, 0:2), 30, T, prob = c(0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)), 6)
mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   NA   NA    0   NA   NA
#[2,]   NA   NA    2   NA   NA
#[3,]   NA    2    1   NA   NA
#[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[6,]    0   NA   NA   NA   NA
ff(mat, 3)
#[1] 4 5 6    
mat[-ff(mat, 3),]      
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   NA   NA    0   NA   NA
#[2,]   NA   NA    2   NA   NA
#[3,]   NA    2    1   NA   NA
```

And some benchmarking:

```
#library(Rcpp) ; sourceCpp("~/ffcpp.cpp")
identical(dat[!cons.missings(dat,3), ], dat[cons_missings(is.na(dat),3), ])
#[1] TRUE
identical(dat[!cons.missings(dat,3), ], dat[-ff(dat, 4), ])
#[1] TRUE
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(dat[!cons.missings(dat,3), ], 
               dat[cons_missings(is.na(dat),3), ],
               dat[-ff(dat, 4), ], times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
                                expr         min          lq      median         uq        max neval
       #dat[!cons.missings(dat, 3), ] 3628.960362 3674.531704 3777.270890 3840.79075 3885.58709    10
 #dat[cons_missings(is.na(dat), 3), ] 5256.550903 5267.137257 5325.497516 5365.13947 5554.88023    10
                  #dat[-ff(dat, 4), ]    6.444897    7.749669    8.971304   11.35649   58.94499    10

#the rows that each function will remove
resff <- ff(dat, 4)
rescons.mis <- which(cons.missings(dat,3)) 
rescons_mis <- seq_len(nrow(dat))[-cons_missings(is.na(dat),3)]

sum(resff != rescons.mis)
#[1] 0
sum(resff != rescons_mis)
#[1] 0
sum(rescons_mis != rescons.mis)
#[1] 0
length(resff)
#[1] 5671
length(rescons.mis)
#[1] 5671
length(rescons_mis)
#[1] 5671
```

Comment: +1! excellent!Indeed it is incredibly faster! Can you explain a little bit your algorithm? it looks like mine but it is faster.

Comment: @agstudy : I neither expect it to be that faster and I re-started many R sessions and re-run the benchmarking many times to check if I've missed anything and embarass myself after posting the answer! :). To be honest, I'm not much into C/C++ so I'm not sure I can figure out what is significantly different between our answers. I'll edit my answer, though, to clarify some steps.

Answer (score 0):

I add another answer using Rcpp since OP is using big matrix. I am not an Rcpp proficient so I can't get better solution even I think I tried to implement an efficient rle missings algorithms.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool maxMissingSequence(IntegerVector x,int n) {

  // Initialise first value
  int lmissings = 1;
  double prev = x[0];
  for(IntegerVector::iterator it = x.begin() + 1; it != x.end(); ++it) {
    if (prev == *it && prev==1)lmissings++;
    if(lmissings >n) break;   // we are OK
    if(*it==0) lmissings =1;  // reset counter
    prev = *it;
  }
  return lmissings >n;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector cons_missings(IntegerMatrix Im, int n ){
   IntegerVector res ; 
   int nrows = Im.nrow();
   for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
      if(!maxMissingSequence(Im(i,_),n))
         res.push_back(i+1);
  return res;
}
```

#### Benchmarkings

```
set.seed(2)
N <- 3*1e5
dat <- matrix(sample(c(1,NA),N,replace=TRUE),ncol=5)

cons.missings <- 
function(dat,n)
apply(is.na(dat),1,function(x){
  yy <- rle(x)
  any(yy$lengths[yy$values]>n)
})


identical(dat[!cons.missings(dat,3),],dat[cons_missings(is.na(dat),3),])
[1] TRUE

system.time(dat[!cons.missings(dat,3),])
   user  system elapsed 
   4.24    0.02    4.35 

> system.time(dat[cons_missings(is.na(dat),3),])
   user  system elapsed 
   6.34    0.00    6.48
```